# Catching exception in class finalizer in UWP apps

Tags: c#, .net, exception, uwp

What are recommended methods to catch exceptions that occur in C# finalizer in UWP ?

AFAIK `Application.Current.UnhandledException` catches exceptions in SynchronizationContext loop, and `TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException` catches Task-related exceptions that were not handled properly.

But i have exception in class Finalizer. How can i catch it ?
If there is a possibility to throw exception in Finalizer - there should be possibility to catch it to perform logging.

I don't see `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` from .NET (it fires on when exception occures on finalizer thread) or `Application.ThreadException` from WinForms.